# Wordpress - get category name of custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

My code returns category name of default post type "post":

```
<div class="row masonary-wrap">

<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '6'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        $categories = get_categories( $args ); 

        foreach ( $categories as $cat ) : ?>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 port-item mb-30 <?php echo esc_attr( $cat->cat_name ); ?>">    
                <div class="project">
                    <div class="proj-img">
                        <div class="proj-overlay">
                            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php
        endforeach;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif; ?>

</div>
```

I need to display category name or better slug of custom post type "project", not of default posts!

Comment: look into this,[URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196719/wordpress-get-category-names-for-a-custom-post-type), [URL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652122/how-to-list-all-category-from-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that. please check the below code

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'project' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```

thanks,